# Call mock method mockito for specific Class<T>

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, mockito, verify

I am wondering to test my interactor and a piece of test code is mocking the Callback interface that is implemented for different objects on BaseInteractor, that all the Interactors implements.

```
    public interface Callback<T> {

    void onSuccess(T response);

    void onError(Exception exception);

}
```

I want to test the onSuccess method and i made this:

```
    @Test
public void shouldGetContributorsSuccess() {

    repository = mock(Repository.class);
    List<Contributor> contributor = getMockContributor();
    GetContributorsInteractor interactor = getFilterReports();
    GetContributorsInteractor.Callback callback = mock(GetContributorsInteractor.Callback.class);

    interactor.execute(contributor.get(0).getUserName(), "Hello_World", callback);

    verify(callback).onSuccess(contributor);
}
```

when I want to mock the Callback in this line:

```
    GetContributorsInteractor.Callback callback = mock(GetContributorsInteractor.Callback.class);
```

after that i call `verify(callback).onSuccess(contributor);`
 and show a warning that says Unchecked call to 'onSuccess(T)' as a member of raw type '... .BaseInteractor.Callback'.

I don't know if I should specify in the **mock** line the specific type as GetContributorsInteractor.Callback but throws an exception or what.

Thanks in advance!

Probably it is because I don't have used mockito before...

**UPDATE**

I suppress the warnings and I found a error that says:

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
callback.onSuccess(
    [com.example.x.iphonedroid.domain.entities.Contributor@2f686d1f]
);
-> at com.example.x.iphonedroid.domain.GetContributorsInteractorTest.shouldGetContributorsSuccess(GetContributorsInteractorTest.java:61)
Actual invocation has different arguments:
callback.onSuccess(
    []
);
```

Probably my error becomes from other part that i don't know how to identify but I think I am giving parameters correctly.

In the last line in verify method I pass a **"List< Contributor >"** and it seems like it would be an empty List.

Comment: I think you need to specify the type of callback: `GetContributorsInteractor.Callback<YourObject> callback = mock(GetContributorsInteractor.Callback.class);`
And now you will have this warning on the `mock...` part. To completely eliminate this warning you can add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` to the method.

Comment: I thought so @Mykhailo but when I do that and put `GetContributorsInteractor.Callback<Contributor> callback = mock(GetContributorsInteractor.Callback.class);`  it is produced an error when I set the callback variable into the ìnteractor.execute` method

Comment: Ok. I saw in my Callback in GetContributorsInteractor needs a **List<Contributor>** so I changed to `GetContributorsInteractor.Callback<List<Contributor>> callback = mock(GetContributorsInteractor.Callback.class);` but now reports me an error that says inside the mock method I need to specify the type too but I don't know how.
@Mykhailo

Comment: Just to clarify, you're not trying to test the onSuccess method, you don't mock the thing you're testing. You're testing the execute method and confirming it calls onSuccess

Comment: @JacobSTL I want to verify that i can call my method OnSuccess with an arrayList and the method executed correctly. I am very new at testing and using mockito so it is probably that I am using in the wrong way.